# How can I change the order of the Multi-index using Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, slice

[image: Data is shown as this Image]

I'd like to know how can I use Python to re-order the "Progress" as "Start-Develop-Middle-Operate"?

Python automatically ordered by alphabetical order but I don't want it to do that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please include all relevant data in text form in the question. We cannot copy it from a screenshot.

Comment: Preferably with code to reproduce your multiindex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['France']*4+['China']*4,'Progress':['Develop','Middle','Operate','Start']*2,'NumTrans':np.random.randint(100,900,8),'TransValue':np.random.randint(10000,9999999,8)})

df = df.set_index(['Country','Progress']).T
print(df)
```

Source Dataframe:

```
Country      France                              China                           
Progress    Develop   Middle  Operate    Start Develop   Middle  Operate    Start
NumTrans        603      661      251      110     747      780      390      346
TransValue  8662422  5226407  4679673  2589011  695373  5655969  2079905  7878596
```

Set as category and define order:

```
df.columns = df.columns.set_levels([df.columns.levels[0],
                      df.columns.levels[1].astype('category').reorder_categories(['Start','Develop','Middle','Operate'])])

#Sort the dataframe using category dtype
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Country       China                             France                           
Progress      Start Develop   Middle  Operate    Start  Develop   Middle  Operate
NumTrans        346     747      780      390      110      603      661      251
TransValue  7878596  695373  5655969  2079905  2589011  8662422  5226407  4679673
```

### Update Testing Missing a progress step for country.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['France']*4+['China']*4,'Progress':['Develop','Middle','Operate','Start']*2,'NumTrans':np.random.randint(100,900,8),'TransValue':np.random.randint(10000,9999999,8)})

df = df.set_index(['Country','Progress']).T
df2 = df.drop(('China','Operate'), axis=1)
df2
```

Input Dataframe

```
Country      France                               China                  
Progress    Develop   Middle  Operate    Start  Develop   Middle    Start
NumTrans        672      496      319      394      346      402      462
TransValue  6341768  5832091  9580341  5739947  6399118  6826113  1501382
```

Astype and sort:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.set_levels([df.columns.levels[0],
                      df2.columns.levels[1].astype('category').reorder_categories(['Start','Develop','Middle','Operate'])])

#Sort the dataframe using category dtype
df2 = df2.sort_index(axis=1)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
Country       China                     France                           
Progress      Start  Develop   Middle    Start  Develop   Middle  Operate
NumTrans        359      496      191      886      685      814      581
TransValue  1369593  8810118  5527613  8970396  1424341  8017561  7749721
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for sharing your coding. But I tried the code, it returns                                             
"AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'sort_index'". It also shows: "'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'columns'". Can I know how to fix this?

Comment: Hrm.. @Alex  What version of pandas are you running?   If you run this code as is does it work?  If so, then we need make sure that your input dataframe has multiindexes.  I can't work with you at this time but I will return later this evening.  Best of luck to you.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your help. It works now. But the code seems not works for if the country missing one or two of the progress...I mean if China only has Develop, Middle, and Operate, the indexed order is not working...

Comment: @Alex the code still works with this given example.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much!